# Extract category from webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am **scraping** different marketplaces which have their own category tree.
I think there can be a kind of NLP based solution to identify the product or item category from web page content.
Please give me some comments if you have understanding.

Comment: Please provide an example. Also what have you tried ?

Comment: Hi - I think you mean ‘scraping’. Scrapping means throwing away.

Comment: @barny From [towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-basics-82f8b5acd45c) "Web Scraping is an automatic way to retrieve unstructured data from website and store them in a structured format. For example, if you want to analyse what kind of face mask can sell better in Singapore, you may want to scrape all the face mask information on E-Commerce website like Lazada."